# Eigenvalue and algebraic multiplicity of some matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the eigenvalue and algebraic multiplicity of $$P=\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\1 & -3 & 3  \\ }$$ My calculations led me to the eigenvalues $0,\pm 1,3$ each of algebraic multiplicity $ 1$. While the book's answer is: the only eigenvalue is $ 1$,of algebraic multiplicity $ 3$. Am I right, if not may you explain why? $$$$Thanks in advance

Comment: The book is right, the only eigenvalue is 1. Maybe you should do the calculations again or post what you did so we can tell you where you went wrong ;)

Comment: One remark: the trace is $3$. So the book is likely correct, and you are certainly wrong, as $0+1+3\neq 3$. Moreover, what is this $\pm 1$? Did you find $4$ eigenvalues? That's impossible in dimension $3$.

Comment: You wrote "$0, \pm 1,3$" which accounts for four eigenvalues, but only three are possible! Cycling the bottom row to the top and the rest of the rows downward, you can see that the resulting matrix (with the same determinant) is upper-triangular with 1's on the diagonal: so, its eigenvalues are clearly all 1.

Comment: If the determinant is not zero, can an eigenvalue be zero? Because that's what you have....

Comment: @ imranfat Thank you very much

Comment: @ rschwieb Thank you very much

Comment: @  julien Thank you very much

Comment: @ Dolma Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if you solve

$$|P- \lambda I| = 0$$

The characteristic polynomial is:

$$-\lambda^3+3 \lambda^2-3 \lambda + 1 = 0$$

This factors as:

$$-(\lambda-1)^3 = 0$$

You get a single eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$

It has algebraic multiplicity $3$.

Comment: @ Amzoti Thank you very much

Comment: Nice feedback for a helpful answer! +1

Comment: Yes, I agree...same sort of day for me :-/

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is in companion form, so the characteristic polynomial can be read off from the bottom row (the polynomial coefficients are the negatives of the bottom row) as $\lambda^3 + (-3) \lambda^2 + (3) \lambda + (-1) = (\lambda-1)^3$.

Comment: @proofy: You are very welcome. If there is any confusion, please give a yell. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I get the same as the book. Let's have a look at where you might have gone wrong. If $M$ is the matrix above and $I$ is the three-by-three identity matrix then the eigenvalues are found by solving $\det(M-\lambda I) = 0$.

$$M-\lambda I = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\lambda & 1 \\ 1 & -3 & 3-\lambda \end{array}\right]$$

I'm going to expand the first row to get the determinant. Let $|N|$ be the determinant:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\left| \begin{array}{ccc} -\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\lambda & 1 \\ 1 & -3 & 3-\lambda \end{array}\right| &=& -\lambda\left|\begin{array}{cc} -\lambda & 1 \\ -3 & 3-\lambda \end{array}\right|-1\left|\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 3-\lambda \end{array}\right|+0\left|\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -\lambda \\ 1 & -3 \end{array}\right| \\
&=& -\lambda(-\lambda(3-\lambda)+3)-1(0-1)+0(0+\lambda) \\
&=& -\lambda^3+3\lambda^2-3\lambda+1 \\
&=& (1-\lambda)^3
\end{array}$$

Hence $\lambda = 1$ is the only eigenvalue of the matrix. Putting $\lambda = 1$ gives
$$M- I = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 & 2 \end{array}\right]$$

The kernel vectors, $[u,v,w]^{\top}$, are given by solving

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 & 2 \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} u \\ v \\ w \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$

In other words: $v-u=0$, $w-v=0$ and $u - 3v + 2w = 0$. The first equation tells us that $u=v$ and the second tells us that $w=v$. Putting this into the third gives $v - 3v + 2v = 0$. This holds *for all* $v$, and so the eigenspace is $[v,v,v]^{\top}$, where you are free to choose $v$, i.e. the line spanned by $[1,1,1]^{\top}$.